# Matching tags in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to match tags with C# and I'm having some trouble getting it to work. I have these tags:

```
<categories=1></categories=1>
```

The `=1` could be really any number. It could be 1, 2, 3 or any other given number. Is there a way to match this tag in C# using IndexOf or RegEx or a better method.

So to give an example of how I want to use it. I would have something like:

```
if (PUT WORKING CODE HERE ONCE FIGURED OUT)
{
    Do Something
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: _MATCHING_CODE_HERE_ is a little bit bstract, isn't it? Do you know that you're looking for `categories`?

Comment: That is just the place holder of the code I would put there once working.

Comment: Is the input, apart from the `=` signs, valid XML?

Comment: Is there any reason that you've tried to invent a sort of s##t xml that isn't xml? Seems silly to me.

Comment: Yea, it will always be valid.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to first make the document valid XML by replacing those equation signs, then use any XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

there is only one valid answer to this need, unless you are doing homeworks and need to learn how to code this yourself...

avoid reinventing things from scratch and use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

it is called Html but also handles XML files, in case you have to do more complex things, like parsing, and don't want or cannot use pure XPath and XML related .NET Framework classes.

see here for some examples: [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)